# Does a charged particle moving in a static electric field experience an EM wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrostatics, reference-frames

If a (varying) force was applied to a charged particle such that it moved towards the (point) source of a static electric field at constant velocity, would that particle in its reference frame experience an EM wave?

The particle would be experiencing time varying electric field, which suggests to me it would experience EM. However, it is moving at constant velocity, and I was also of the understanding that acceleration was required for EM to be emitted.

Comment: There is no reason for closure. It is a well-phrased question.

Answer (score 0):

No. EM wave is a specific kind of EM field, where a pattern of EM field on a line moves along the line as a translating solid body would (mathematically, this means that value of  a physical quantity depends on position $x$ and time $t$ only in such a way that it is function of the expression $x-vt$, where $v$ is velocity of the wave). In your example, in the frame of the charged particle, there is no magnetic field at the position of the particle, and electric field strength increases in time. So there is no EM field pattern moving as solid body, acting on the particle. There is electric field changing in time, but it would not be correct to call it EM wave.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems I was wrong in my initial assumptions. As a follow up, In your answer, you state there is no magnetic field, however does this not contradict Maxwells equations in the reference frame we have discussed?

Comment: You're right, there is magnetic field in the space around the source. But it vanishes at the position of the particle. I've edited my answer.